# How to use `Linked Model` feature of Core ML 3?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, coreml, coremltools

[As WWDC suggested](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/704/), a `linked model` feature is supported in Core ML 3., which allows developers re-use the same `mlmodelc` to save space.

There are also two parameters named [`linkedModelFileName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlparameterkey/3227893-linkedmodelfilename) and [`linkedModelSearchPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlparameterkey/3227894-linkedmodelsearchpath) in the documentation.

But I didn't see any tutorials or examples about how to use it, except the proto of `Linked Model` is defined in [the documentation of `coremltools`](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/sections/LinkedModel.html).

So I'm just wondering if there is anybody knowing the exact way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how to use a linked model and make it updatable (just ignore the updatable bit for your use case):

https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/master/examples/updatable_models/updatable_linked_model.ipynb